# Perf fails at showing LLC-loads

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, profiling, perf

Although I have `LLC-loads`and `LLC-load-misses` listed in `perf list`, if I run:

`perf stat --repeat 2 -e cycles:u -e instructions:u -e LLC-loads -e LLC-load-misses binary arguments`

on my Linux machine, I get 0 for both `LLC-loads`and `LLC-load-misses`. I also tried `perf record` + `perf report`. Does anybody know why? The CPU is E5-2670 Sandy Bridge.

Comment: is it x86_64 architecture?

Comment: `perf list` always list all events defined in kernel. There set of predefined events is always not fully implemented: either older kernel can't map some events to your hardware; or your hardware have no such performance counters; or you have no access to events??? (try with sudo or from root user). You can check other events listed in `perf list` or update your kernel if it is old (the LL counters were implemented in 2011: https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/5/9/80)

Comment: @osgx Yes, these are listed in `perf list` and the kernel is newer than 2011.

Comment: a3mlord, you can try andikleen/pmu-tools from github - https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools - it has better support of Intel hardware performance monitors with `ocperf` then predefined events from `perf list`. You can also try `toplev.py` from pmu-tools to find counters to check; or read Intel manuals to get right counter names

Comment: Please provide kernel version `uname -a`

Comment: @Ivan Linux 3.0.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 21 15:50:59 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux